# Angular ngFor in multiarray

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, ngfor

I have array like this

```
  array = [
    {
      naslov: 'Naslov1',
      podnaslov: 'Podnaslov1',
      odgovori: {
        odgovor0: 'Odgovor 11',
        odgovor1: 'Odgovor 12'
      }
    },
    {
      naslov: 'Naslov2',
      podnaslov: 'Podnaslov2',
      odgovori: {
        odgovor0: 'Odgovor 21',
        odgovor1: 'Odgovor 22'
      }
    },
    {
      naslov: 'Naslov3',
      podnaslov: 'Podnaslov3',
      odgovori: {
        odgovor0: 'Odgovor 31',
        odgovor1: 'Odgovor 32'
      }
    }
  ];
```

I am trying to loop inside html liket this but i didnt manage to get field **odgovori**. Here is my html

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of array, let i=index">
    <h1>{{item.naslov}}</h1>
    <p>{{item.podnaslov}}</p>
    <div *ngFor="let odgovor of item.odgovori[i], let i=index">
      <p>{{odgovor}}{{i}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `odgovori` is an object, not an array. Try the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).

Answer (score 1):

Since `odgovori` is an object not an array, you will need to use the `keyvalue` pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

```html
<div *ngFor="let odgovor of item.odgovori | keyvalue, let i=index">
  <p>{{odgovor.value}}{{i}}</p>
</div>
```

Or judging by the keys in your `odgovori` object, you could probably do it like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let odgovor of item.odgovori | keyvalue">
  <p>{{odgovor.key}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array, let i=index">
    <h1>{{item.naslov}}</h1>
    <p>{{item.podnaslov}}</p>
    <div *ngFor="let odgovor of item.odgovori | keyvalue, let i=index">
        <p>{{odgovor.value}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```